# Azure Managed Identity Python Running in Docker Container

Tags: python-3.x, azure, docker-container, azure-managed-identity

I have created a python function app which reads client certificate from Azure key vault. It uses managed identity to read the certificate. Here is my code

```
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
certificate_client = CertificateClient(key_vault_url, credential)
certificate = certificate_client.get_certificate(key_vault_certificate_name)
```

It is working fine in VS code and also working in Azure when I deploy it but not working when I deploy it to a container running on my system. I get following error

> Exception: ServiceRequestError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1007)

This error could be misleading (I believe) and I think it is related to managed identity because docker can't access azure. Or may be this is a configuration issue because I am behind a proxy configured by company. I have installed the necessary certificate in the docker file but no success.

I have also given azure container app which I pushed to azure, full access to key vault just like the function app but still get error.

Is there any way to make sure It is a certificate error and not an identity error?

Update 1 - I have added connection_verify=False to all three constructors and now I get following error, which confirms I am having a certificate error and also the default identity error

> ClientAuthenticationError: DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.

```
  Attempted credentials:
    EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
  Visit https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot to troubleshoot this issue.

    ManagedIdentityCredential: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no response from the IMDS endpoint.

    SharedTokenCacheCredential: SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.

    AzureCliCredential: Azure CLI not found on path

    AzurePowerShellCredential: PowerShell is not installed

    AzureDeveloperCliCredential: Azure Developer CLI could not be found.
```

Here is my docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.10-appservice

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY Certificates/*.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
RUN update-ca-certificates --verbose --fresh

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host 
pypi.python.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org --no-cache-dir -r /requirements.txt

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot
```

Comment: what do you mean by docker ? are you using any specific containerized product ? app service / aks / container app ?

Comment: yes container app, running a function app.

Comment: So this: [Azure Container Apps hosting of Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-container-apps-hosting)

Comment: are you encountering the issue only locally while running the function app inside a container or as well after dpeloying to a container app ?

Comment: Also could you share your dockerfile